# SQL Window Function to find the second highest order date of each customer at the order level

Tags: sql, datatable, aggregate-functions, window-functions, presto

I have a table with the following fields:

```
| order_id  | order_date  | customer_id  | second_highest_order_date_of_the_customer
| 12345     | 2020-11-01  | customer_ABC | 2020-05-01
| 67891     | 2020-05-01  | customer_ABC | 2020-02-01
| 00531     | 2020-02-01  | customer_ABC | 2020-01-01
| 00789     | 2020-01-01  | customer_ABC |
```

I am finding it hard to calculate the **second_highest_order_date_of_the_customer** column in SQL.
I can calculate the second-highest date for each customer overall using window functions, But I am struggling to find the second_highest_date at the order level which should not be past the order_date in the said row.

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The [`nth_value()`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html#nth_value) window function does what you want:

```
select t.*,
       nth_value(order_date, 2) over (partition by customer_id order by order_date desc) as penultimate_order_date
from t;
```

In case English is not your first language, *penultimate* is a nifty word that means the "second from last in a sequence".

Comment: Thank you for your response. My database has duplicate order_ids and order_dates(1 for each item purchased). Is it possible to get the next most recent date?

Comment: And I am trying to get the second most recent date at the order level. In my original example for the 3rd entry in which the order ID is 00531, I need the calculated column to give me '2020-01-01' as that is the second most recent date on which the customer_ABC had ordered at that time. But your code gives me 2020-02-01 which is the second_most_recent_date of purchase for that customer OVERALL. Please let me know if you need any additional information. Thank you again for your help